# Jquery hover for the lowest element layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

For example i got this html:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

div2 is display:none.

So is there a jquery method, to trigger a hover function on div1 that diplays div2.

like this:

```
$('#div1').hover(function(){
    $('#div2').stop().fadeIn();
}, function(){
    $('#div2').stop().fadeOut();
});
```

i've got a bigger code but its too large to post. Every function i tried works not so fine. I want to trigger the hover ONLY on the lowest layer element div1. But mostly if the `fadeIn()` is triggered and the cursor moves over it the hover effect on div1 ends.

Are there hover function that includes ALL child elements?

Comment: use `mouserover` will work for all child elements.

Comment: isn't `hover()` a combination of `mouserover()` and `mouseout` ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to fade in all children when the parent is hovered?

Seeing as you have CSS tagged in your question, I'll give a CSS answer:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88n2Z/)

```
#div1 *{
   opacity:0;
   transition:opacity 200ms ease-in;
}
#div1:hover *{
   opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks for your fast answer. This i didn't know this css solution, very interesting. But this was only an example for me the real function has divs which are animated left and top so that moves permanantly. If i hover one of these, it should stop and show the child elements. the normal jquery hover function works but everytimte i hove the child element the out-function get trigged and than the in-function for the child elements. That throws ugly errors :/

Comment: Can you also manage the movement using CSS transitions/animations?

Comment: not all i think. the coordinates where divs move to, are rendered intime randomly. But i didn't try to do that in css. I'll give you feedback in some minutes.

Comment: thanks so far but the animation stop function throw the errors at all. i think now i have tried all solutions i know. `moseenter/mouseleave`/`hover`/`mouseover/mouseout`/`css`. Any other ideas? :/

Answer (score 1):

How about using Nth Child selector of Jquery. I couldn't paste an example here because I am currently outside.
But this should work if you read it.
http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/